# Error while trying to initialise a class in scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, type-mismatch

I am trying to make a class for the purpose of adding rational numbers

```
class Rational(val numerator: Int, val denominator: Int) {
  require(denominator != 0)

  def this(numerator: Int) = this(numerator, 1)

  def +(addend: Rational): Rational = {
    new EquivalentRationals(this, addend).sum
  }

  def +(addend: Int): Rational =
    new Rational(numerator + (denominator*addend), denominator)

  override def toString = numerator + "/" + denominator
}

class EquivalentRationals(a: Rational, b: Rational) {
  val first: Rational =
    new Rational(a.numerator * b.denominator, a.denominator * b.denominator)

  val second: Rational =
    new Rational(b.numerator * a.denominator, b.denominator * a.denominator)

  def sum(): Rational =
    new Rational(first.numerator + second.numerator, second.denominator)

  def difference(): Rational =
    new Rational(first.numerator - second.numerator, second.denominator)

  override def toString = first + " " + second
}
```

I get the following error when i try to create an object out of the first class

> :23: error: type mismatch;
>   found   : Rational(in object $iw)(in object $iw)(in object $iw)(in object $iw)
>   required: Rational(in object $iw)(in object $iw)(in object $iw)(in object $iw)
>   new EquivalentRationals(this,addend).sum()

I would like to know why this occurs and i would also be grateful for any suggestions of alternative approaches to adding rational numbers which also use a separate class for representing equivalent fractions. (there is a rational class which already accomplishes this without using a separate class in the book "programming in scala")
edit: The problem only seems to occur when  using scala-mode in emacs. I tried to run it by selecting the option "load file in interpreter", so although it runs via the command line i am still curious as to why it doesn't in "inferior-scala"

Comment: try changing new EquivalentRationals(this,addend).sum() to (new EquivalentRationals(this,addend)).sum()

Comment: What is your scala version? Works for me in `scala 2.10.1`.

Comment: @SimonTodd: `new EquivalentRationals(this,addend).sum()` works fine.

Comment: scala 2.10.2 ,unfortunately (new EquivalentRationals(this,addend)).sum()  does not work

Comment: @HerrChar: Are you sure? [See this.](http://ideone.com/DpIPpc) It works: stdout - "3/2".

Comment: @senia After seeing your link i tried compiling it with scalac via command line and it worked!Previously i had been using scala-mode in emacs and i tried to run it by selecting the option "load file in interpreter", so although it runs via the command line i am still curious as to why it doesn't in "inferior-scala".Thanks for answering my original question

Comment: @HerrChar, I think you left an interesting question unasked. It is not about Rational, but about what is going on with ENSIME. Can you edit your question and put your sbt build, ensime plugin used and the command that you issued to emacs?